# what is wrong when checking if the objects is nil

Tags: objective-c, object, init, null

I have read the docs from apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

It says that we can check if object is null like...

```
 XYZPerson *somePerson;
    // somePerson is automatically set to nil
 if (somePerson != nil) {
        // somePerson points to an object
    }
```

Most probably i am doing something wrong but need your help to find what it is.
I have a class C2,I create the C2 object but not initialising,when checking with the code below ,app writes NOT NİL to output.What am i doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

```
C2 * o3;

    if (o3 != nil) {
        NSLog(@"NOT NİLLLL");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NOT");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike members of classes that are zeroed out on initialization, local variables are not initialized automatically by pre-ARC compilers. If you would like your local `o3` to be `nil`, you need to initialize it yourself:

```
C2 * o3 = nil;
```

The behavior of not initializing locals unless explicitly directed by the program comes from C: there, too, the locals are not initialized by default.

Comment: Doesn't that directly contradict the linked documentation? "[Initializing variables] isn’t necessary for object pointers, because the compiler will automatically set the variable to nil if you don’t specify any other initial value."

Comment: @melpomene That's true if you are using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), and it only applies to Objective-C object pointers, not pointers to other things.

Comment: Yep, the Apple documentation is notoriously incomplete and unreliable, especially with regard to version changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i tried it assigning nil and works better:) your answer has to be specified at document.